# Is it possible to customize the parallax effect of ImageView in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, imageview, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Is it possible to change the value of parallax effect to trigger early before the image collapses as well as it expands?
On the image I provided below, the rectangle stroke image is entering the collapse state without fading out so it looks kinda ugly and thought to fix it by having it fade before entering the collapse state and fading in in expanded state. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Why don’t you control yourself its visibility? Add a OnOffsetChangedListener to the AppBarLayout and make the stroke visible when offset == 0.

Comment: try this github code............... https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample